# Only one row user defined table can be passed to stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT 
    @MaxSeq = (CASE 
                  WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM app_Attachments 
                        WHERE app_Attachments.AppId = @appID) <= 0 
                     THEN 1 
                     ELSE (SELECT (MAX(seq)+1) 
                           FROM app_Attachments 
                           WHERE app_Attachments.AppId = @appID)
               END)

DECLARE @Id INT;

SELECT @Id = (COALESCE((SELECT MAX(Id)+1 FROM app_Attachments), 1))

INSERT INTO app_Attachments (Id, AppID, AttName, AttContentType, AttData, AddedBy, AddedDate, Seq)
    SELECT 
        @Id, AppId, ImgNames, ImgType, Bytes, @AddedBy, @AddedDate, @MaxSeq 
    FROM
        @Attachments --user defined table

CREATE TYPE [dbo].[AppsAttachments] AS TABLE
       (
            [AppId] [INT] NULL,
            [Bytes] [VARBINARY](MAX) NULL,
            [ImgNames] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
            [ImgType] [NVARCHAR](200) NULL
       )
```

Insert into table using stored procedure that has user defined table as parameter only success if table passed has one row, it was working well when the primary key is set as identity, after I changed the primary key into manual integer to be entered the problem occurred

Comment: What is your question? Did you get an error msg?

Comment: i put a try catch and cannt handle the error its just not inserting if the table i pass contains more than one raw , i guess its the primary key coz i havenot defined it in the table

Comment: please show the schema for `app_Attachments` and `@Attachments`. And what does `AppsAttachments` related to your query ?

Comment: put i tried it when the primary key was identity , it was working even if seq is presented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if Id is not identity, then you need to ensure the Id is not duplicates. Use `Row_number()` to generate a running sequence of number

```
insert into app_Attachments (Id,AppID,AttName,AttContentType,AttData,AddedBy,AddedDate,Seq)
select  @Id + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY AppId) - 1,
        AppId,
        ImgNames,
        ImgType,
        Bytes,
        @AddedBy,
        @AddedDate,
        @MaxSeq 
from    @Attachments --user defined table
```

if you also need to increase the `Seq` as well, add a `row_number()` to the query

Comment: Nice catch, `MAX()` won't  work cause the defined table has more than 1 row. +1 :)